# Change out put of the_post_thumbnail in PHP

Tags: php

I am brand new to PHP. I've messed with wordpress on it but not really with the code behind it. I am trying to speed up the loading time of our wordpress site but I am having some trouble. PHP uses `the_post_thumbnail` to load the HTML code for some of the posts' images. I have this code to delay loading of the images a little so the page can load first and then the images will load:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
jQuery('img[source]').prepend(function(){
    var source = jQuery(this).attr('source');
    jQuery(this).attr('src', source);
});
});
```

This works very well on another site I work on written in coldfusion and normal html. So what I'm trying to do is change the output of `the_post_thumbnail` to have a 'source' attribute that has the actual source path and the initial `src` value will have a default loading gif.

My first thought was to build another function or I guess as PHP calls it, add a filter like this:

```
add_filter('post_thumbnail_html', 'thumbnail_filter');
function thumbail_filter() {
$default_attr = array(
    'src'   => $src,
    'class' => "attachment-$size",
    'alt'   => trim(strip_tags( $wp_postmeta->_wp_attachment_image_alt )),
);
the_post_thumbnail($default_attr);
// you can alter the resulted HTML here
$html = the_post_thumbnail($default_attr);
return $html;
}
```

This didn't actually broke the page and didn't show any images even when I haven't called the thumbnail_filter function.

My next guess as to what to do was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808746/dynamically-replace-the-src-attributes-of-all-img-tags-redux). Can someone who is a little more experienced in PHP and wordpress help me out? Maybe the first one is the right way to go but I'm just doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filters are *WordPress* not PHP.

Second, you have called the `thumbnail_filter` function. You hooked it to `post_thumbnail_html` so any time a function runs that applies that filter, like `the_post_thumbnail`, your function runs. If you think about that, you will see that you have a bit of a Loop there. The filter calls a function (twice) that applies the filter.

Third, `the_post_thumbnail` will echo the image. That is not what you want. And I am a bit confused about what these two lines (not counting the comment)...

```
the_post_thumbnail($default_attr);
// you can alter the resulted HTML here
$html = the_post_thumbnail($default_attr);
```

... are meant to do.

I think you are somewhat confused about how filters work.

This [particular filter passes several parameters](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/post-thumbnail-template.php#L98):

```
return apply_filters( 'post_thumbnail_html', $html, $post_id, $post_thumbnail_id, $size, $attr );
```

You only need the first for what you are doing. You need to alter that input and return it, like so:

```
function thumbnail_filter($html) {
  $pattern = '|src="([^"]*)"|';
  $html = preg_replace($pattern,'src="/absolute/loading/gif/path.gif" source="$1"',$html);
  return $html;
}
add_filter('post_thumbnail_html', 'thumbnail_filter');
```

Please be sure to use the *absolute* URL for your loading gif by using a function like `get_stylesheet_directory_uri`, or whatever is appropriate in your case. Do not use a relative URL. It will cause trouble.

Comment: @JohannesPille : Thanks for fixing that. I hang my head in shame. 0_o

Comment: As far as my judgement goes, you can hold that head of yours up high, despite having made the horrendous mistake of having missed 12 whitespaces... ;)

Comment: Can I place this anywhere in functions.php or does it have a special place to go? I had it close to the end of the file but it again wouldn't load or display the pictures.

Comment: I had it in a `mu-plugins` file but it should work from `functions.php`. Location shouldn't matter but make sure it is inside `PHP` opening and closing tags.